# @ user addressing in comments doesn't work sometimes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

I have noticed that several times recently, just now with [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114715/i-cant-figure-out-what-action-makes-hidden-files-bashrc-etc-show-up-and-ac).

I start a comment and want to address the OP. I write "@" and start typing the name but the autocompletion doesn't appear. Even worse: I write it manually and after sending the comment that part is erased. The user account still exists, though. I do not remember the other questions (or addressed users), though.

Comment: This is when you're doing it under the actual Q, right? This seems to be how it works. If the OP leaves a comment, you can then @ him/her, if you try to do this before they've left a comment then it will erase it on you.

Comment: <--- I just typed your name and it's gone now! Now leave a comment!

Comment: The OP always gets notified of comments on their posts. So we strip out the @name as it is just noise.

Comment: @slm Test: Does this change the behaviour?

Comment: @HaukeLaging <--- just typed your name again. See now that you commented your name shows up 8-)

Comment: @Oded - notice that it now allows the name to show up? I always assumed that the OP's name showed up here so that if ppl were @'ing each other that we could distinguish comments directed to the OP, but only after he/she commented at least 1 time.

Comment: @slm - If only one other person commented, then there is never confusion, which is why we strip it out. However, after a third person enters into comments, disambiguation may be needed, so we don't.

Comment: OK so the 3rd person joining is what triggers it, not the OP leaving a comment?